# XSLT Not Taking When Test Selection

Tags: xml, xslt, testing

I've been working on something for my boss, a website that displays the web-services of a ticketing system.  The web-service spits out an XML file based on a query.  My problem is, when I try to set conditions for output, I either get an error or it skips all the way to the "otherwise" entry when the array containing the XML entries for each ticket clearly match what I have in my test.  I'm new to XSLT and have only what I've looked into to go off of.  Can someone look at what I have and explain why this isn't working?  I know it's just something to do with the test expression.

### XML (output in array, don't have original XML file)

```
    Array
(
    [RowCount] => 3
    [HasError] => false
    [ErrorMessage] => Array
        (
        )

    [StackTrace] => Array
        (
        )

    [IncidentList] => Array
        (
            [Incident] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [GroupName] => EXTERNAL_SUPPORT
                            [IncidentNumber] => 229178
                            [OpenDateAndTime] => 2011-05-09T10:42:33
                            [State] => O
                            [StatusID] => EMAIL WIP
                            [SubjectID] => MAGIC
                            [UrgencyID] => NORMAL
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [GroupName] => CISS SYSTEMS
                            [IncidentNumber] => 203863
                            [OpenDateAndTime] => 2010-05-25T09:16:55
                            [State] => C
                            [StatusID] => CLOSED
                            [SubjectID] => ULID EXPIRATION
                            [UrgencyID] => NORMAL
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [GroupName] => HELP DESK 1ST LEVEL
                            [IncidentNumber] => 186909
                            [OpenDateAndTime] => 2009-09-11T09:58:44
                            [State] => C
                            [StatusID] => CLOSED
                            [SubjectID] => QUESTION
                            [UrgencyID] => NORMAL
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What I'm using is this snippet of XSLT to display a table based on the State being O, C, or otherwise, display a message that there are no tickets to display.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table id="myTable" class="list">
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Incident</td>
            <td class="title">Category</td>
            <td class="title">State</td>
            <td class="title">Status</td>
            <td class="title">Date</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="State = 'O'">
                <xsl:for-each select="Results/IncidentList/Incident">
                    <tr>
                        <td>#<xsl:value-of select="IncidentNumber"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="SubjectID"/></td>
                        <td>OPEN</td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="StatusID"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
                                <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="OpenDateAndTime" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="State = 'C'">
                <xsl:for-each select="Results/IncidentList/Incident">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="closed">#<xsl:value-of select="IncidentNumber"/></td>
                        <td class="closed"><xsl:value-of select="SubjectID"/></td>
                        <td class="closed">CLOSED</td>
                        <td class="closed"></td>
                        <td class="closed">
                            <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
                                <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="OpenDateAndTime" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">There are no incidents to display</td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried every iteration of the test expression and I either get errors or it skips directly to the otherwise.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there no way for you to get hold of the XML file that the web service spits out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant this instead of your 'xsl:when's:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Results/IncidentList/Incident[State = 'O']">
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="Results/IncidentList/Incident[State = 'C']">
```

etc. The context on your 'when' condition in your example is not an Incident, but the root of the XML document. So you could also prefer:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Results/IncidentList/Incident[State]">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="State = 'O'">..</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="State = 'C'">..</xsl:when>
      <Xsl:otherwise>..</xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Another alternative is using templates:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   ..
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Results/IncidentList/Incident[State]" />
   ..
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Results/IncidentList/Incident[State = 'O']">..</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Results/IncidentList/Incident[State = 'C']">..</xsl:template>
..
```

Comment: Robert, you **ROCK**.  That worked perfectly.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- Your test for the value of `State` needs to be inside of the `xsl:for-each` where the context is `Incident` and a relative path to `State` will match.
- A more "DRY" approach would be to move the `xsl:choose` inside of the `<td>` where you apply the different value for the `State` and avoid repeating the same column logic for all the others.
- **Wouldn't you want to produce the row with the message "There are no incidents to display" when there were no `Results/IncidentsList/Incident` elements?**  In your current implementation (and in the other answers posted), you would only receive that message if there is a `Results/IncidentList/Incident` and the `State` value is neither "O" or "C".  If there were none, you would not produce that row.

Below is an implementation that addresses the items described above:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
        <table id="myTable" class="list">
            <tr>
                <td class="title">Incident</td>
                <td class="title">Category</td>
                <td class="title">State</td>
                <td class="title">Status</td>
                <td class="title">Date</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Results/IncidentList/Incident">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Results/IncidentList/Incident">
                         <tr>
                             <td>#<xsl:value-of select="IncidentNumber"/></td>
                             <td><xsl:value-of select="SubjectID"/></td>
                             <td>
                                 <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="State = 'O'">  
                                        <xsl:text>OPEN</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                     <xsl:when test="State = 'C'">
                                         <xsl:text>CLOSED</xsl:text>
                                     </xsl:when>
                                  </xsl:choose>
                             </td>
                             <td><xsl:value-of select="StatusID"/></td>
                             <td>
                                 <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
                                     <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="OpenDateAndTime" />
                                 </xsl:call-template>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">There are no incidents to display</td>
                 </tr>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
```